# Feel wheel rotation when pressing hard on the brake

Tags: brakes

I was driving in the interstate (Nissan 2019 Versa Note) and the car in front of me stopped abruptly, so I had to do the same thing. I pressed down on the brake pedal really hard and for a moment I could feel some sort of rotation (I think it came from the wheel?) on my foot that was on the brake pedal. Anyone knows what caused this and if it's harmful for the car?

Answer (score 1):

If it was a vibrating feeling like the pedal was going up and down very quickly, then that could have been the anti-lock brake (ABS) coming on.

If this sounds like the feeling you were experiencing, then this is normal under very hard braking and will not have done any harm.

If you are still concerned, then best thing is to get the brakes checked by a mechanic if you don’t know how to do it yourself.

Comment: A buzzing sensation is certainly ABS.  Anything else, like a warped brake disc, will be at a lower frequency, a few times a second.